# Can't pickle <local> object

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I am having trouble getting my class pickled.[This is an example of my function that creates a spike class with certain attributes]

```
def load_pt(ptname, data_directory):
   """
    input: ptname, a string containing the name of the patient you want to load. example: 'ABC123'
    output: object: spike ---- contains: List of 1000 random spikes: spike.select   and their subsequent:
    values: spike.values, chlabels: spike.chlabels, fs: spike.fs, soz channels: spike.soz
   """       

    val = mat73.loadmat(data_directory + '/values/values_{}.mat'.format(ptname))
    val2 = val['values_all']
    select_spikes = loadmat(data_directory + '/randi/randi_{}.mat'.format(ptname))
    select_spikes = select_spikes['select_spikes']
    ch_labels = loadmat(data_directory + '/chlabels/chlabels_{}.mat'.format(ptname))
    ch_labels = ch_labels['ch_labels_all']
    fs_all = loadmat(data_directory + '/fs/fs_{}.mat'.format(ptname))
    fs_all = fs_all['fs_all']
    SOZ_chlabels = pd.read_csv(data_directory + '/pt_data/SOZ_channels.csv')
    pt_all = pd.read_csv(data_directory + '/pt_data/ptname_all.csv') 
    pt_name = ("'{}'".format(ptname))
    whichpt = pt_all.index[pt_all['ptname'] == pt_name].tolist()
    clean_SOZ_chlabels = prep_clean_soz(SOZ_chlabels)
    
    global spike
    class spike:
        values = val2
        select=select_spikes
        chlabels = ch_labels
        fs = fs_all
        soz = clean_SOZ_chlabels[whichpt[0]]

    return spike
```

I understand that the code requires some global effect. I'm fairly new to coding and would love some pointers.

The error I get is:

> AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'load_pt..spike'

Things I've tried:

- add a global spike before initializing my class object in my load_pt function (did not work)
  get error: Can't get attribute 'spike' on <module 'ied_functions' from 'directory_name'

Comment: You must post code as text, not as images.

Comment: It is unusual to define a specialized class in a function. Probably you only need an object of the class holding the data as instance attributes you are currently storing as class attributes. In this case you can define a generic class at global level and create an object in the function. Pickle will then be able to store the object(s).

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate the class Spike first before you can return it.
To do this the class does not need to be global. After defining the class instantiate it by writing `spike = Spike()`. After that, you can return the instance of spike that you just created with `return spike`.

Into the pickle function you now need to pass `load_pt` and **not** `load_pt.spike`. Now you are passing the function load_pt which returns an instance of the class Spike. `load_pt.spike` references a local variable inside of load_pt which was never created.

See the entire code here:

```py
import pickle

def load_pt(ptname, data_directory):
    # input: ptname, a string containing the name of the patient you want to load. example: 'ABC123'
    # output: object: spike ---- contains: List of 1000 random spikes: spike.select   and their subsequent:
    # values: spike.values, chlabels: spike.chlabels, fs: spike.fs, soz channels: spike.soz

    val = mat73.loadmat(data_directory + '/values/values_{}.mat'.format(ptname))
    val2 = val['values_all']
    select_spikes = loadmat(data_directory + '/randi/randi_{}.mat'.format(ptname))
    select_spikes = select_spikes['select_spikes']
    ch_labels = loadmat(data_directory + '/chlabels/chlabels_{}.mat'.format(ptname))
    ch_labels = ch_labels['ch_labels_all']
    fs_all = loadmat(data_directory + '/fs/fs_{}.mat'.format(ptname))
    fs_all = fs_all['fs_all']
    SOZ_chlabels = pd.read_csv(data_directory + '/pt_data/SOZ_channels.csv')
    pt_all = pd.read_csv(data_directory + '/pt_data/ptname_all.csv')
    pt_name = ("'{}'".format(ptname))
    whichpt = pt_all.index[pt_all['ptname'] == pt_name].tolist()
    clean_SOZ_chlabels = prep_clean_soz(SOZ_chlabels)

    class Spike:
        values = val2
        select = select_spikes
        chlabels = ch_labels
        fs = fs_all
        soz = clean_SOZ_chlabels[whichpt[0]]

    spike = Spike()

    return spike

pickle.dump(load_pt, open( "spike.pkl", "wb" ))
```

Hope this helpes! :)

## Edit:

Also I would follow @MichaelButschers advice:

> It is unusual to define a specialized class in a function. Probably you only need an object of the class holding the data as instance attributes you are currently storing as class attributes. In this case you can define a generic class at global level and create an object in the function.

That might look something like this:

```py
import pickle

def load_pt(ptname, data_directory):
    # input: ptname, a string containing the name of the patient you want to load. example: 'ABC123'
    # output: object: spike ---- contains: List of 1000 random spikes: spike.select   and their subsequent:
    # values: spike.values, chlabels: spike.chlabels, fs: spike.fs, soz channels: spike.soz

    val2 = val['values_all']
    select_spikes = select_spikes['select_spikes']
    ch_labels = ch_labels['ch_labels_all']
    fs_all = loadmat(data_directory + '/fs/fs_{}.mat'.format(ptname))
    fs_all = fs_all['fs_all']
    SOZ_chlabels = pd.read_csv(data_directory + '/pt_data/SOZ_channels.csv')
    pt_all = pd.read_csv(data_directory + '/pt_data/ptname_all.csv')
    pt_name = ("'{}'".format(ptname))
    whichpt = pt_all.index[pt_all['ptname'] == pt_name].tolist()
    clean_SOZ_chlabels = prep_clean_soz(SOZ_chlabels)

    spike = Spike(val2, select_spikes, ch_labels, fs_all, clean_SOZ_chlabels[whichpt[0]])

    return spike

class Spike():
    def __init__(self, values, select, chlabels, fs, soz):
        self.values = values
        self.select = select
        self.chlabels = chlabels
        self.fs = fs
        self.soz = soz

spike = load_pt('pt_name', 'data_directory')

pickle.dump(spike, open( "spike.pkl", "wb" ))
print(pickle.load(open( "spike.pkl", "rb" )))
```

Comment: This was a huge help. A tremendous thank you to you and Michael Butscher. It's working now. Sorry for the noobie class implementation, this is the first time I've worked with them!

Comment: Happy it helped, you’re welcome! Never excuse yourself for being a noob at something. ;)